# I have program which I want to compare bring dates and bring desired data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I write all details on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=04540f31ee1fb826739489655c134d17) I have two tables Named GAZZETED_DAYS with column (GAZZETED_DATE, DESCRIPTION)  and PAY_IN_OUT with column (EMP_CODE,ATT_DATE) please check data I already pasted in dbfiddle what i want output is like that

```
01-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
02-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
03-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
04-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
05-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
06-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
07-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
08-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
09-JAN-21   The Day of:     Its Holyday two
10-JAN-21   The Day of:     Present
```

when it compare with att_date then it shows like this in all dates which have range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have been outer join; something like this:

```
SQL> declare
  2    descr      varchar2(90);
  3    gz_dt      date;
  4    date1      date :=to_date('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
  5    date2      date :=to_date('2021-01-31','YYYY-MM-DD');
  6    vatt_date  date;
  7    vempcode   number;
  8    cursor c_gzdt is
  9      select g.gazzeted_date, g.description, p.att_date, p.emp_code
 10      from pay_in_out p left join gazzeted_days g
 11         on p.att_date = g.gazzeted_date
 12        and gazzeted_date between date1 and date2
 13        and p.emp_code=111
 14      order by p.att_date;
 15  begin
 16    open c_gzdt;
 17    loop
 18      fetch c_gzdt into gz_dt, descr, vatt_date, vempcode ;
 19      exit when c_gzdt%notfound;
 20
 21      if vatt_date = gz_dt then
 22         dbms_output.put_line(vatt_date||' THE DAY OF : '||descr);
 23      else
 24         dbms_output.put_line(vatt_date||' THE DAY OF : '||'PRESENT');
 25      end if;
 26
 27    end loop;
 28    close c_gzdt;
 29  end;
 30  /
```

which results in

```
01.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
02.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
03.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
04.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
05.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
06.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
07.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
08.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
09.01.21 THE DAY OF : Its Holyday two
10.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
11.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
12.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
13.01.21 THE DAY OF : Its Holyday three
14.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
15.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
16.01.21 THE DAY OF : Its Holyday four
17.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
18.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
19.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
20.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
21.01.21 THE DAY OF : Its Holyday five
22.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
23.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
24.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
25.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
26.01.21 THE DAY OF : Its Holyday six
27.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
28.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
29.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
30.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
31.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

As of **Oracle Reports** issue: skip PL/SQL entirely and use slightly modified cursor query as report's query. In line #8 you'd still use parameters, most probably created under report's **User parameters** within the Object Navigator. Report would, I presume, get their values from elsewhere (such as Oracle Forms or Apex or ...). The same goes for the `ID`, I believe - you don't really want to hardcode `111`, do you?

```
SQL> select p.att_date     ||
  2       ' THE DAY OF : ' ||
  3         case when p.att_date = g.gazzeted_date then g.description
  4              else 'PRESENT'
  5         end result
  6  from pay_in_out p left join gazzeted_days g
  7     on p.att_date = g.gazzeted_date
  8    and gazzeted_date between date '2021-01-01' and date '2021-01-31'
  9    and p.emp_code = 111
 10  order by p.att_date;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------
01.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
02.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
03.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
04.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
05.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
06.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
07.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
08.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
09.01.21 THE DAY OF : Its Holyday two
10.01.21 THE DAY OF : PRESENT
<snip>
```

---

**[Outer join in Reports]**

Ah, yes ... in Reports, you'll have to use the "old" Oracle's outer join `(+)` operator. The same goes for `case` - use `decode` instead:

```
select p.att_date     ||
     ' THE DAY OF : ' || 
       decode(p.att_date, g.gazzeted_date, g.description, 'PRESENT') result
from pay_in_out p, gazzeted_days g 
where p.att_date = g.gazzeted_date (+)
  and g.gazzeted_date (+) between date '2021-01-01' and date '2021-01-31'
  and p.emp_code = 111
order by p.att_date;
```

Comment: Respected @Littlefoot please only 1 thing which you can help me please I write code for oracle report for same thing can you guide me how to implement this on that I write code on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c0000b479e15663a48d42a4aaa9cc80)

Comment: I added some more code to the bottom of the answer. Have a look, please.

Comment: it just give me first result mean only first records in between dates not all data brings in please check once [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c0000b479e15663a48d42a4aaa9cc80)

Comment: Certainly, because it exits the loop at the first RETURN. It seems you didn't understand what I said in the answer. You don't need to use PL/SQL at all. As report's query, use SELECT statement I posted while editing the answer (marked with **Oracle Reports**).

Comment: can you change my query pleaseeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: just please tell me what i can add in my code to check and put data in all code it gives me all dates and desc which are compered and having in this loop work through all code till the dates between [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c0000b479e15663a48d42a4aaa9cc80)

Comment: I tried **Report Query ** but left join is not working is there something which I can do in my query because its working all fine just need to go for all dates please help me

Comment: Oracle Reports doesn't *speak* `left join` so you'll have to use Oracle's `(+)` outer join operator. I added that code into the answer.

Comment: it throw me error `encountered the symbol **case** when expecting `

Comment: is there any possibility that my code can work

Comment: Oh well, CASE won't work either in Reports. Use DECODE instead - I fixed it, have a look.

Comment: won’t succeed. Answer is only in that code which I write just need of to loop go for next all record till the Between datesany idea about that