# I write a function which exits when first record found want to go for the all dates oracle reports

Tags: oracle, plsql, oraclereports

I write this function which give me first record then loop terminate I want that it can go through all dates which are given can anyone help me please

```
function CF_GZDT2Formula return Char is

descr      varchar2(90);
gz_dt      date;

CURSOR C_GZDT is  
      select  gazzeted_date, description 
  from gazzeted_days 
  where gazzeted_date between :DATE1 and :DATE2;

BEGIN
 OPEN C_GZDT;  
   LOOP  
      FETCH C_GZDT into gz_dt, descr ;
      EXIT WHEN C_GZDT%notfound;
      IF
         
        :ATT_DATE = GZ_DT THEN 
             RETURN descr;      
             
      ELSE RETURN 'PRESENT';
        END IF;         
      END LOOP;  
            CLOSE C_GZDT;
            
  exception 
       when No_data_found 
         then return 'NO DATA FOUND';
  END;
```

Can any one tell me how can go through all dates between :date1 and :date2 because it suspended on first record i want to go through all data

Comment: it's not clear what you want to have ; only one record ? ordered by which critera ? and what's the version of the database ?

Comment: database version is 11g r2, and using in oracle reports  table named `gazzeted_days` hvae more records than 1 in between two days just want to iterate through all record mean date1 and date2 have dates between 1 to 30 and there are 5 records in table it show all records on there own date and date shown in :att_date

Comment: try to change return type to `SYS_REFCURSOR`, but I couldn't understand why do you need to return more than one rows within Reports? It already has embedded query objects in order to bring multiple rows.

Comment: Remember that with your other question on this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66839928/i-have-program-which-i-want-to-compare-bring-dates-and-bring-desired-data that as soon as you put a dbfiddle together with a reproducible example of what you wanted to happen, someone was able to help you almost immediately rather than having to ask a bunch of questions to try to clarify the problem.

Comment: @Justin I didn’t get yet answer from past 3 days :(  and struck here

Comment: In the question I linked to, you got an answer, accepted the answer, and thanked Littlefoot.  So I'm rather confused.

Comment: @Justin yes as in sql it worked but not on report where I was stuck

Comment: Please edit your original question to add this information then.  Opening new questions just causes new sets of people to ask you the same basic set of clarifying questions to try to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Include the code you're actually running, the error(s) you're getting and/or the results that you are getting and the results you want for the data in your sample.  I've not dealt with Oracle Reports myself.  Littlefoot's latest answer looks pretty reasonable to me, I'm not quite sure why it doesn't meet your needs.